# How do other DAWs deal with interleaved 5.1 files from Pro Tools?

Tags: pro-tools, 5.1, surround-sound

I have a library of 5.1 effects and was wondering how other DAWs (Nuendo/Logic/Fairlight/Etc) deal with importing interleaved Pro Tools polyphonic wav files. I know I can save the effects as multiple mono files but I'm trying to keep things neat.

Thanks,
Bruce

Comment: I only use Pro Tools, but just for clarification, are you referring to a matrix encoded or polyphonic wav file? That will affect the answers you get from people. I assume you mean the latter, but just in case... ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the file is in fact a true WAV file (has the .wav tag), then Nuendo will read it fine.  WAV is a general format.  It is not specific to Ptools.  Nuendo (I'm on ver 4.3?) has multichannel tracks dedicated to multichannel material.  My guess is that you can just drag it into Nuendo (havent done it myself).  You may have to create a multichannel track of the 5.1 variety and then drag it in.

BTW I am in Game Audio and I love Nuendo.

Comment: Thanks David. I guess my question was a little misleading. It was the interleaved aspect that I was concerned with. I just wanted to double check with other workstations played nice with them. By the way, Nuendo looks great. Glad to hear you like it. 
Thanks Again,
Bruce

Comment: PS: We send a lot of our mixes to video post houses and they always ask for multiple mono files.
Thanks Again
Bruce

Answer (score 1):

The only "catch" is that ProTools ALWAYS uses the "Film Surround" order (LCRLsRSLf) in interleaved files - there's no option for SMPTE format (LRClfLSRS). This can cause files to be played back in the wrong channels when imported into some DAWS - I believe Nuendo can do either/or, but I haven't really used it since version 2!